# TypeError when two specific values are encountered

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype

All numbers except 86 and 93 works well. Only 86 and 93 throw a `TypeError`.
But I want to use 86 and 93 to include all numbers. What should I do?

```
from tkinter import *

app=Tk()
app.title("progress")
app.geometry("800x500+365+120")

q={'weigh':100,'goal':75,'now':86} #or 'now':93

def bar():
    first=int(q['weigh'])
    achieve=int(q['goal'])
    today=int(q['now'])

    def num(n):
        for z in range(0,n):
            y=(first-achieve)*(z/100)
            if (first-today)==y:
                return z
            if today<achieve:
                z=100
                return z
    rate=int(num(101)/10)
    for _ in range(1,rate+1):
        Entry(app,bg="blue",width=4).pack(side=LEFT)
    for _ in range(rate,10):
        Entry(app,width=4).pack(side=LEFT)

Button(app,text="OK",command=bar).pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: `num()` returned `None`, so you can debug it and find out where problem is

Comment: @OlvinRoght TypeError occurs on rate=int(num(101)/10).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment: `num()` returned `None`, so you can debug it and find out where problem is

You never enter one of the two if blocks in `num()`. Which means you never reach `return z`. In Python all methods implicitly return `None`, if there is no explicit `return` statement. So you may want to deal with the case that you iterate over the `range(0,n)` and never enter one of the if blocks. You should return something in that case or raise an error to deal with this case.

EDIT:
You can raise an error when you looped over the whole range. Then you will see that this is the actual problem. You never enter one of the if blocks. You can either catch the error or add some meaningful return value like `return 0` or what ever makes sense in your code.

```
def num(n):
    for z in range(0,n):
        y=(first-achieve)*(z/100)
        if (first-today)==y:
            return z
        if today<achieve:
            z=100
            return z
     raise ValueError
```

Comment: TypeError occurs on rate=int(num(101)/10).

Comment: Yep, looks like num() returns None.